# how to get a custom column like timeslot-> delivery_title, delivery_date in magento order grid

Tags: magento-1.9

I need your support, Delivery Time and Date in Order Grid How to load .....

```
Table Name = timeslot 
Table Fields = id, delivery_title, delivery_date, order_id
```

my question is how to call this data in my order grid.... please help me......

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
{
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());
$select = $collection->getSelect();
$resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
$select->join(
array('timeslot' => $resource->getTableName('deliverytime/timeslot')),
'order.timeslot_order_id = timeslot.order_id',
array('timeslot_delivery_title' => 'delivery_title')
array('timeslot_delivery_date' => 'delivery_date')
);
}

protected function _prepareColumns()
{
$this->addColumn('delivery_title', array(
'header' => Mage::helper('deliverytime')->__('Time Slot'),
'index' => 'delivery_title',
'type' => 'options',
'width' => '120px',
'options' => Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getAkDeliverytime(),
));

$this->addColumn('delivery_date', array(
'header' => Mage::helper('deliverytime')->__('Deliver Date'),
'index' => 'delivery_date',
'type' => 'options',
'width' => '120px',
'options' => Mage::getSingleton('deliverytime/deliverytime')->getAkDeliverytime(),
));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try below code Might be help to you change index values as follow and may it will solve your probelm

```
protected function _prepareColumns()
{
$this->addColumn('delivery_title', array(
'header' => Mage::helper('deliverytime')->__('Time Slot'),
'index' => 'timeslot.timeslot_delivery_title',
'type' => 'options',
'width' => '120px',
'options' => Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getAkDeliverytime(),
));

$this->addColumn('delivery_date', array(
'header' => Mage::helper('deliverytime')->__('Deliver Date'),
'index' => 'timeslot.timeslot_delivery_date',
'type' => 'options',
'width' => '120px',
'options' => Mage::getSingleton('deliverytime/deliverytime')->getAkDeliverytime(),
));
}
```